# Show all the partitions of $\{(0,1),(3,1),(5,5),(2,1)\}$. Calculate intra-block distance between unique pairs.

Tags: set-partition

So given 4 elements, there are 15 partitions.

The formula for d is $d((x_1, x_2),(y_1, y_2)) = [(x_1−y_1)^2+ (x_2−y_2)^2]^{1/2}.$

I've calculated the distance for one of the partitions is $\{\{(0,1),(2,1)\},\{(3,1),(5,5)\}\}$.

The distance is $2 + (2)*(5^{1/2})$.

It was calculated by taking doing `{(DISTANCE between (0,1),(2,1)) + (DISTANCE between (3,1),(5,5))}`

and for another partition that has 4 singleton elements: $\{ \{(0,1)\}, \{(3,1)\}, \{(5,5)\}, \{(2,1)\} \}$

Intra-block distance for this partition would go like this: $$
d((0,1),(3,1)) +d((0,1,),(5,5)) +d((0,1),(2,1)) + d((3,1),(5,5))\\ + d((3,1),(2,1)) + d((5,5),(2,1))$$

My question is, for a partition that has 3 elements that has 2 singleton pairs and 1 element that has 2 coordinates like so: $\{\{(0,1),(2,1)\},\{(3,1)\},\{(5,5)\}\}$, how do I calculate the intrablock distance for this partition.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 mathjax reference for typing maths.

Comment: Hi, can you give me a definition or a reference to the intra-block distance? Somehow I can't find it. I'm familiar with $d(A,B)=\inf\{d(a,b)~:~a\in A,~b\in B\}$ which yields $d(\{x,\hat{x}\},\{y\})=\min\{d(x,y),~d(\hat{x},y)\}$. But this might be wrong for the "intra-block distance"...

Comment: Show all the partitions of `{(0,1),(3,1),(5,5),(2,1)}`. Each element is a pair `(x1, x2) ∈ R2` . A standard metric `d:R2×R2→R is :d((x1, x2),(y1, y2))   =   [(x1−y1)^2+ (x2−y2)^2]^0.5` (Just the l^2−norm or Euclidean distance). Create a table that calculates the intra block distances between all unique pairs. I’ve calculated one shown below.

Comment: You defined the metric as in your question, but you didn't defined the intra block distance. There should be a definition of the distance between sets or the distance between partitions.